# Extra variables in form - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I think Im taking the wrong approach to this and have tried to find the best approach on the web but so far no luck.

I have a projects model, which has many messages and users. The messages belong to both projects and users (as displayed below). So I need to pass in both the project id and user id into the message form. I know this should be pretty straightforward, but Im obviously messing it up. Not sure at this stage wether using http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag is necessarily the best idea either.

Any help would be awesome.

Project Model:

```
 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :users
   has_many :messages, :dependent => :destroy
 end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :password
 attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

 has_many :projects
 belongs_to :projects
 has_many :messages
end
```

Message Model:

```
 class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :message
   belongs_to :project 
   validates :title, :presence => true
   validates :message, :presence => true
 end
```

Projects show:

```
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @title = @project.title
    @curent_user = current_user
    @message = Message.new    
    begin
      @messages = @project.messages
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound      
    end
  end
```

/shared/_message.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for @message do |f| %> 
<%= f.label :title %>:
<%= f.text_field :title %><br>

<%= f.label :message  %>
<%= f.text_area :message  %>

<%= f.submit  %>

  <% end %>
```

Message create action

```
 def create
   @message  = @project.messages.build(params[:message])
   if @message.save
     flash[:success] = "Message created!"
     redirect_to root_path
   else
     render 'pages/home'
   end
 end
```

Appreciate your time, just trying to identify how I transfer the user_id/project_id into the from field so it's passed in at message creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the project_id/user_id in the controller so they can't be modified by end users when submitting the forms.

As you're using @project.messages.build in the message controller create action the project_id should automatically be set.
You can then set the user with @message.user = @current_user